# Making JavaFX executable jar with images from resources folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, executable-jar

I have read and tried dozens of posts that relate to this topic, but none are working out. I am getting null pointer errors in every case, I have tried copying my image directory to every folder that it might be referenced, and even just dumping all of the image files in with the source and class files, nothing is working! I have successfully loaded fonts, css stylesheets and text files using getResource() methods but I cannot get my images to include properly in an executable jar file.

Here is the code section with some (not all) of the alternatives I have tried commented out. This is code that is part of the Class constructor. The project is in IntelliJ.

A solution will be so appreciated, thanks!

```
public class Letter extends Button
{
    private char value;
    private Image image;
    private ImageView iv;
    private String imagePath;
    private URL imgUrl;
    private InputStream is;
    private boolean clicked;
    private boolean validNext;
    int x, y;


    /**
     * CONSTRUCTOR for Letter objects
     * @param value char value for key, a-z
     * @param size size of image for key, in px
     */
    Letter(char value, int size)
    {


        this.value = value;
        this.imagePath = "resources/images/" + value + ".png";
        //this.imagePath = "/resources/images/" + value + ".png";
        //this.imagePath = "images/" + value + ".png";
        this.is = getClass().
                getClassLoader().
                getResourceAsStream(imagePath);
        this.imgUrl = this.getClass().getResource(imagePath);
        this.image = new Image(this.imgUrl.toExternalForm(), size, size, true, true);
        //this.image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath));
        //this.image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgUrl.toString()));
        this.iv = new ImageView(image);
        this.setGraphic(iv);
        this.clicked = false;
        this.validNext = false;
        this.x = -1;
        this.y = -1;
        this.setId("button");
        if (this.validNext) this.setBlendMode(BlendMode.GREEN);
    }
```

And my directory structure:

```
root
  out
    artifacts/Project/project.jar
  production
    Project
      images
      css
      text
      fonts
      (all .class build files)
  resources
    images
    css
    text
    fonts
  src
    (all source .java files)
```

Comment: Can you list the contents of the jar file (`jar tf project.jar` from the command line if you can't do that in your IDE). Are the images there, and if so what is the path to them?

Comment: They are in the jar under resources/images/*.png as well as images/*.png

Comment: Oops hit enter too soon. I also had added the resources folder to "directory content" in the IntelliJ Artifacts settings which perhaps accounts for the duplicate content. I see that the .class files are at the root level, and also that the .java files are included in the jar under a src directory, but not sure how/why the src folder is added! Thank you for your help James..